# Как перехватить оконные сообщения чужого окна?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Появилась необходимость читать оконные сообщения чужого окна. Для этого есть функция `SetWindowsHookEx`, но сам дойти не могу, каким образом перехватить у сторонней программы оконное сообщение, приведённые примеры по ссылкам из поисковиков не о чем не говорят.

Суть задачи: Есть приложение А, после обработки события, результат приходит как сообщение `TE_COMPLETE`. Приложению Б, нужно считать-перехватить это оконные сообщения, и выполнить свою функцию.

Помогите хотя бы примером, дальше как всё работает, по примеру сам разберусь.

Comment: Что конкретно не получается? Документацию читали внимательно? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Примеров полно на гитхабе: https://github.com/search?l=pascal&q=SetWindowsHookEx&ref=opensearch&type=Code

Answer (score 4):

В WinApi нет такого сообщения как `TE_COMPLETE`, скорее всего, это какая-то определённая в приложении A константа, соответственно, вам нужно узнать значение этой константы.

Плюс, что чтобы перехватывать сообщения, вам нужно выполнить 2 шага:

- повесить хук при помощи `SetWindowsHookEx` на события типа `WH_GETMESSAGE` **или другого типа**, в зависимости от того, как сообщение `TE_COMPLETE` передаётся и обрабатывается в приложении А. И особое внимание нужно уделить последнему параметру в функции `SetWindowsHookEx` - туда в обязательном порядке нужно передать `ID` текущего потока, если вы обрабатываете хук не в dll. Используйте для этого `GetCurrentThreadID()`.
- при получении хука в обработчике, сравнить значение переданное в перехваченном сообщении со своей константой `TE_COMPLETE` и при совпадении, выполнить необходимое действие.

Замечательнейшая справка по хукам вот тут: [Хуки в Win32](http://rsdn.ru/article/baseserv/winhooks.xml) - после её изучения от корки до корки, у вас не должно остаться вопросов по хукам.

Примеров использования хуков полно, вот вам один из них: [uFixFMXForm.pas](https://github.com/freeonterminate/delphi/blob/afeecd08f4fcd3a2f1619dce3b9b1fea545f5a71/FMXForm/uFixFMXForm.pas) - тут вешается хук на события типа `WH_CALLWNDPROC` и обрабатываются два события `WM_CREATE` и `WM_SHOWWINDOW` с некоторой целью.